# How to add an image (jpg) to an existing layout using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, jpg

I have 1500 MXDs with the same template layout, and need to insert other images for the all MXDs, can I do this using Python?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Do you already have the picture element in the layout or do you want to add a new picture element.It's not possible to add a new layout element with arcpy.

Comment: i have one  picture element in layout , ist posible copy that  element picture?

Comment: It is possible to clone a text or graphic element but I don't think you can with a picture element but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the source of an existing picture element there is a code snippet in the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000s000000).You would of course have to know the name of your picture element.

> The following script will find an image by name and set its data
>   source to a new             location.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == "Photo":
        elm.sourceImage = r"C:\Project\Data\NewPhoto.bmp"
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

> The following script demonstrates how different pictures can be
>   switched out for each page in a Data Driven Pages enabled map
>   document. There is a different picture for each page. The pictures are
>   named Photo1.png, Photo2.png, Photo3.png, etc to match the
>   corresponding page numbers.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
pict = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT", "photo")[0]
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    pict.sourceImage = r"C:\Project\Data\Photo{0}.png".format(pageNum)
    print("Exporting page {0} of {1}"
          .format(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID,
                  mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Project\Page{0}.pdf".format(pageNum))
del mxd
```